# HTML: Floating left and right resolution / resize problems by %

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with the below HTML when resizing the window;

1: Right bar suddenly drops down when the width is resized too small.

2: Spacing between the content and right bar gets larger as the width gets larger.

```
<style type="text/css">

#content {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  border:2px solid #00ff00;
}

#rightbar {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 17%;
  float: right;
  border:2px solid #ff0000;
}

#rightbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #F0F4FF;
  margin: 3px;
}
#rightbar a:hover { background-color: #1D3E93; color: #fff; }
</style>

<div id="content">contents</div>
<div id="rightbar">
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 2</a>
  <a href="#">link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies I dont know why some is coming out as big bold. I really can't get use to stackoverflows formatting its quite iritating. If someone could correct that would be smashing! :)

Comment: `max-width` is not supported in IE6. To fix that, add `expression(this.width > 200 ? 200: true);` to `#rightbar`.

Comment: Remember to read these too:  http://giveupandusetables.com/  and http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/

Comment: @Wouter van Nifterick: If you use conditional statements for IE6, you can just use width as IE6 treats that as a min-width anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get the result you want:

1. put the right bar before the content
   in the html, remove the width from
   the content and give it a right
   margin instead (width of the right
   bar + something extra)
2. position the right bar absolutely on the right, remove the width from
   the content and give it a right
   margin instead (see number 1.)

By the way, the problem is that you are mixing absolute and relative widths and what you see is exactly what you are supposed to see.

**Edit:** After re-reading your question, I think that with overflow:hidden (makes it a nice square block) on the content part, you can get it to work in combination with 1. without the margin:

```
<style type="text/css">

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  border:2px solid #00ff00;
}

#rightbar {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 17%;
  float: right;
  border:2px solid #ff0000;
}

#rightbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #F0F4FF;
  margin: 3px;
}
#rightbar a:hover { background-color: #1D3E93; color: #fff; }
</style>

<div id="rightbar">
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 2</a>
  <a href="#">link 3</a>
</div>
<!-- content needs to be placed after rightbar -->
<div id="content">contents</div>
```

Comment: I can't get 1. to work it now spans on two lines. I don't see how positioning absolutely would work either and after trying it positions the rightbar to the top left hand side of the screen, as I thought it would. Have I misunderstood? It seems the first option is the most likeable anyhow.

Comment: Works very well thanks. Curious as to how that overflow: hidden works

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you resize too small, the percentages width will be smaller than the text content within your element. The browser cannot concatenate words, so the element is forced to have a min-width. Try putting the elements in a wrapper with an assigned min-width.
2. Between these two bars you have a space of 3%. 3% of 1000px is 30px. 3% of 2000px is 60px. Therefore if you right element is floating right, it makes sense you'll see that additional space. Try floating the element left.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Ideally I would like the #content to take up all available width.